# Redirecting users on a custom login & registration page and allowing only admin to login by default wp-login.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want users to register & login only by custom pages not by default pages, instead only admin can login by the default wp-login.php

I found this .. but it is redirecting login & register both on same page. google.com in this case.

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://google.com/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post "you can't do that answers" because it is very easy to go wrong, but generally speaking you can't do this. Until someone logs in, WordPress doesn't know if that person is an admin or not. How are you going to toggle based on information that is not available?

There are only a few of not very good solutions I can think of:

1. If your admin(s) have a static IP, or static IPs, you could switch based on that. Of course, this won't work if an admin tries to log in from Mom's house or from a coffee shop.
2. You could set some very long term cookie (not any cookie used by WordPress) that marks a user as an admin and switch on that. This, of course, only works for users who are on computers that have the cookie set.
3. You could create two custom login pages-- `user-login.php` and `admin-login.php`-- and never publish the later publicly. You'd then redirect all logins to `user-login.php` except for attempts to get to `admin-login.php`, which presumably only your admins know about. That is really just obfuscation but maybe that will work for you.

Either solution is going to be unstable and work sometimes but not others.

Redirecting users to some particular page *after* login is pretty easy. The hard part is using different login pages for users *before* they log in.